# sqlite3 not selecting anything when I use AND operator

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to select something from the database in `sqlite3`.

```
import sqlite3


conn = sqlite3.connect("db_informatii_principal.db")
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("CREATE TABLE persoane (id integer PRIMARY KEY, nume text, prenume text, telefon text, varsta text, adresa text, inaltime text, instagram text, detalii text)")
conn.commit()


c.execute("INSERT INTO persoane VALUES(NULL, 'Mustea', 'David', '0425698333', '17', 'Exemplu Adresa 1', '182', 'george.george', 'Ii place sa bea')")
conn.commit()
lista = ["David", "Mustea"]
c.execute(f"SELECT * FROM persoane WHERE nume = '{lista[0] or lista[1]}' AND prenume = '{lista[0] or lista[1]}'")



for x in c.fetchall():
    print(x)
```

I am using the AND operator in `sqlite3` and the or operator in f-string in python, and it's giving me no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your f-string is substituting the Python expression `lista[0] or lista[1]`, which will return "David".  I suspect you wanted `WHERE (name = '{lista[0]}' OR name = '{lista[1]}') AND (prenume = '{lista[0]}' OR prenume = '{lista[1]}')`, but there are many better ways to do this.  You should NEVER handle this kind of string substitution yourself.  Let the database do it.  It knows the quoting rules.  Your code would fail, for example, if you looked for the name "O'Shea".

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM persoane WHERE name IN (?,?) AND prenume IN (?,?);",  lista + lista )
```